# nginx, fastcgi and how to rewrite a URL

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, fastcgi

I have a very simple rewrite in nginx x using fastcgi.

Suppose my domain is www.test.com/test.fcgi

How do I rewrite to www.test.com?  If I go to www.test.com/test.fcgi it works.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;


    location ~ \.fcgi$ {
                    rewrite ^/test.fcgi/(.*)$ $1 last;
        root   /var/www;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    #fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/nginx.socket;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.html;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you really wouldn't use a .fcgi file like that with Nginx, so it's hard to answer the question as asked. Nginx works with FasCGI the same way it works with other upstream servers, by passing the request to a Unix or TCP socket.

You would rewrite the request using one of the standard methods for rewriting a request.In your location section use something like this:

```
rewrite ^/test.fcgi/(.*)$ $1 last;
```

Then, you pass the request to a daemon listening for FastFGI requests, like this:

```
fastcgi_pass localhost:8001;
fastcgi_index index.fcgi;
```

You might need other options depending on the backend processand the specifics of your setup, if you provide us with moreinformation, we may be able to help further.

For documentation and examples for these two modules see (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule)[here] and (

Comment: server {
        listen   80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
 
        
  location ~ \.fcgi$ {
                        rewrite ^/test.fcgi/(.*)$ $1 last;
   root   /var/www;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        #fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/nginx.socket;
   fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index  index.html;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
  }
  
  



 }

Comment: Well....I want to rewrite.  to run the page I have to go to http://127.0.0.1/test.fcgi but if I go to http://127.0.0.1/ I get page not found.  I changed the index to fastcgi_index test.fcgi;

Comment: In sum...I just want to go to 127.0.0.1 to run the script but instead I have to go to 127.0.0.1/test.fcgi

Comment: what language or framework are you passing these requests to? Nginx won't spawn Cgi or Fcgi handlers on it's own, it expects them to already be listening. The rwrite should remove that path butI'm not sure it's going to solve the problem by itself.

Comment: I am using nginx on ubunto.  I use spawn-fcgi -u root -g root -G www-data -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -f /var/www/test.fcgi to spawn.

Comment: Okay, inthatcase itdoesn't seem like dispatch.fcgi needs to be in the REQUEST_URI at all, so you shouldn't need to rewrite the url. What is the source of the original url, why would itinclude dispatch,fcgi.The point I'm tryingto make is Nginix has a different approach to CGI, it doesn't depend on the filename of the actual scriptwhen dispatching requests, justtheaddress inthe locationblock. If your applicationrequires that dispatch,fcgi be in the url, the rewrite line should work, but most likely it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nginx config,guess it will help you.

```
location = / {
        root /var/www/
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.html;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```